# react native api calls using axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, axios

I have nodeJs back end where i have created this api

```
app.post("/addInvoice", (req, res) => {
  let invoice = req.body;
  var sql =
    "INSERT INTO invoice (address, email, billnumber, price, status) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, 'sent');";
  mysqlConnection.query(
    sql,
    [
      invoice.address,
      invoice.customeremail,
      invoice.billnumber,
      invoice.totalprice,
    ],
    (err, rows, fields) => {
      if (!err) {
        res.send(rows);
      } else {
        res.send(err);
      }
    }
  );
});
```

when I call this API using post man it works perfectly.

but now i need to call it on buttonclick from my react-native app.

```
axios
      .post("http://localhost:3000/addInvoice", {
        address: address,
        customeremail: email,
        billnumber: invoicenumber,
        totalprice: totalPrice,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        alert(response);
      });
```

I nothing happens when I send this and the alert(responce) returns nothing.

what could be the problem?

Comment: try this: then((response) => { console.log(response); }).catch((error)=> console.log("error",error), what will be logged???

Comment: the log is error [Error: Network Error] @ZahraMirali

Comment: I think it has something to do with the app being run on my cell phone -> a different url should be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Emulator (or Phone) is a device on it's own that is not running on the same IP(localhost or 127.0.0.1) as your web browser, postman or your server.

In order to make request to your server from your emulator (or phone) you need to access your server via your computer IP Address: On windows get your IP Address by running ipconfig on the command prompt, or maybe here: system preferences > Network > Advanced > TCP/IP > IPv4 Address.

Instead of http://localhost:port you should use http://your_ip_address:port

Comment: yes exactly but im scanning a QR code and testing the app on my cell phone

Comment: okay it worked i put my IP address instead. THANKS a lot
but i have a question, if i want to send the project to someone else he should change the url in the whole code?
or is there a solution?

Comment: if he is your coworker and you want to send him both backend and frontend, he can change the IP address, but if you want to send your application to somebody to test it,    no he should not change the IP, solution: 1.your pc should be turn on when he is testing your app (otherwise your application can not call the Api) 2. deploy your nodeJs back end to a server and replace "localhost" with the server address

Comment: hello again, i'm sorry for bothering you but can you help me with one more small issue in react native?

Comment: sure, if I be able to answer :)

Comment: its about react navigation, i want to navigate to another component on button click

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: can you send me a private chat link so we can discuss this in chat please?
sorry for bothering you